Auth0 internal and external URL configuration
I am using Openid connect for Auth0. Below is my Startup class
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Auth0",
    Authority = auth0Domain,
    ClientId = auth0ClientId,
    ClientSecret = auth0Secret,
    RedirectUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url +"/callback",.
    Notifications = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
    {

        RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
        {
            string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
            string requesturl = string.Empty;

            if (appBaseUrl.Contains("abc"))
            {
                requesturl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:XCagRedirectUri"];
            }
            else
            {
                requesturl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:RedirectUri"];
            }
            context.ProtocolMessage.AuthorizationEndpoint = auth0Domain;
            context.ProtocolMessage.ClientId = auth0ClientId;
            context.ProtocolMessage.ClientSecret = auth0Secret;
            context.ProtocolMessage.ClientAssertionType = "Auth0";
            context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = requesturl;
            context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = requesturl;

            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
        },

When I use internal url in browser, I get an error

You sent  http://myexternalurl.com and expected http://localurl.com

If I am commenting RedirectURI from the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions, then I get an exception "as you passed null". I am also passing redirect inside notification. I am new to this implementation. Please suggest some points here. All suggestions are most welcome.
